# Nami wallet address format to addr_test1 format

Tags: wallet, smart-contract, address, nami-wallet, decode

lets say i have the following address for recieving funds:
addr_test1qzu70xm8hsez6nvmpgk4gjf48ev0y2hw5w7nf8xaxc658lzwczusckqvzzg630pxnzwj3pqza5q4c8r504ffq6v2zh6qgznxt7

when i try and get the wallet address  (by using Berry-Pool nami wallet) i get:
00b9e79b67bc322d4d9b0a2d5449353e58f22aeea3bd349cdd363543fc4ec0b90c580c1091a8bc26989d288402ed015c1c747d5290698a15f4

how can i go from 00b9e79b67bc322d4d9b0a2d5449353e58f22aeea3bd349cdd363543fc4ec0b90c580c1091a8bc26989d288402ed015c1c747d5290698a15f4
to addr_test1qzu70xm8hsez6nvmpgk4gjf48ev0y2hw5w7nf8xaxc658lzwczusckqvzzg630pxnzwj3pqza5q4c8r504ffq6v2zh6qgznxt7

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also you can use Cardano Serialization Lib https://github.com/Emurgo/cardano-serialization-lib

with the class Adress and the method Address.toBech32() :

```
let HexAddress = "00b9e79b67bc322d4d9b0a2d5449353e58f22aeea3bd349cdd363543fc4ec0b90c580c1091a8bc26989d288402ed015c1c747d5290698a15f4"

console.log(Address.from_bytes(Buffer.from(HexAddress,"hex")).to_bech32())
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for. is there a way to use this library in vuejs?

Answer (score 1):

They are encoded in different formats as the followings:

Bech32 Format:

> addr_test1qzu70xm8hsez6nvmpgk4gjf48ev0y2hw5w7nf8xaxc658lzwczusckqvzzg630pxnzwj3pqza5q4c8r504ffq6v2zh6qgznxt7

Hex Format:

> 0b9e79b67bc322d4d9b0a2d5449353e58f22aeea3bd349cdd363543fc4ec0b90c580c1091a8bc26989d288402ed015c1c747d5290698a15f4

IOHK provides an executable and haskell lib for that in this [repo](https://github.com/input-output-hk/bech32).

To Hex,

```
bech32 <<< addr_test1qzu70xm8hsez6nvmpgk4gjf48ev0y2hw5w7nf8xaxc658lzwczusckqvzzg630pxnzwj3pqza5q4c8r504ffq6v2zh6qgznxt7
```

To Bech32,

```
bech32 addr_test <<< 00b9e79b67bc322d4d9b0a2d5449353e58f22aeea3bd349cdd363543fc4ec0b90c580c1091a8bc26989d288402ed015c1c747d5290698a15f4
```